# Controlling values in .NET 6 templates

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a .NET 6 solution template that I maintain. Like other templates, if the user chooses "Foo" as the name of the solution, the C# namespaces have the sourceName value replaced with Foo, along with class names that have the sourceName value in them. For instance, if you choose to have EF in the output, you'll get an `IFooDbContext`.

However, if you run the template with a period in the name, bad things happen. For example, `dotnet new mytemplate -n Foo.Bar`, I get a class called `IFoo.BarDbContext`, which is clearly not valid C#.

Is there a way in the dotnet templating system to remove the period so that if comes out as `IFooBarDbContext`? I've spent about an hour looking around on Google prior to posting this question, but didn't see anything obvious. If the answer is no, I'll just require that the user specify the name of the DbContext should they choose to include EF.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: Absolutely! Sorry, I should've done that in the first place. The repository is here: https://github.com/StaticSphere/clean-architecture-dotnet-template. And the template.json file can be thus found here: https://github.com/StaticSphere/clean-architecture-dotnet-template/blob/main/.template.config/template.json. Thanks!

Comment: Why can't *you* remove it, before you give the user supplied data to the templating system?

Comment: Please edit the question and add relevant parts of the code.

Comment: That's what I'm unsure of how to do, @CaiusJard. I've looked for samples of how to do this, and couldn't find any results.

Comment: You're struggling with how to replace a character in a string with nothing?

Comment: Essentially, yes. I wasn't able to find a way to have the template engine modify the string passed in from `dotnet new` to remove the period.

Here's part of one of the files in the template:

`public interface ICleanArchTemplateDbContext
{
    ...
}
`

If they pass in Foo.Bar, it will name the interface `IFoo.BarDbContext`, rather than `IFooBarDbContext`. I want the latter. But, I'm thinking that just making them name the context on the command line is the way to actually go here.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I was still not able to figure out a good way to do this. My Entity Framework DbContext class, in the template, is named in a way that it will be replaced with the project name when creating a new project. I decided to just rename the DbContext class to ApplicationDbContext. Now, with or without a dot in the name doesn't matter, as the EF DbContext class is not renamed. The end user can rename the DbContext themselves if they want to via a new parameter that I'm adding in; otherwise it just stays as ApplicationDbContext.

Thanks for taking a look, but I'm going to go ahead and move on from this, having found a solution that will work.

Comment: So like `$safeitemname$` ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/template-parameters?view=vs-2022